# Не обновляются изменения

Tags: modx

Вношу изменения в html и css код. Но никаких изменений не происходит. Если удаляю папку cash, сайт вообще не запускается. Доступа к админке не имею.

Comment: Попробуйте обновлять кеш браузера, а не удалять папку `cash` из корня. Скорее всего для сайта настроена система кеширования, и чтобы увидеть изменения надо локально чистить кеш

Comment: Пробывал очищать кеш, и менял порт(локальный сервер). Не помогло.